# redirecting output to two different files without using tee

Tags: shell, unix

i want to redirect the output of a file to two diff files .

I know I can use tee, but i didint want the output to be printed on the screen.

any suggestions .

```
ls > okay.txt
```

Comment: Questions about using Unix shell belong on http://unix.stackexchange.com/. But first you have to better explain what you want. Especially it is not clear what you want to [`diff`(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) and why you want to avoid [`tee`(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) (tee has nothing to do with console).

Comment: sorry i didnt know that..frankly y does it deserve downvote ? i have mentioned clearly that i want to redirect output of a command to two different files ..when i use tee it displays the output on the console i dont eant that to happen . Read the QUESTION AGAIN @Jan Hudec

Comment: No, you mentioned you want output to two **diff** files. That is not synonymous with "different" as you'd understand if you actually read my comment (the word is a link).

Comment: Tee has everything to do with console @jan Hudec ..please first learn about tee before you answer . it redirects the output to console and also to the files we mention ...

Comment: I know `tee` very well. It has nothing to do with _console_. It copies (no, it does not redirect, it has to copy) to _standard output_ and the file we mention. _Standard output_ and _console_ are very different things.

Answer (score 2):

`tee` can redirect to multiple files, and you can prevent any output to your console by redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
echo "Hello there" | tee file1.txt file2.txt > /dev/null
```

Comment: thanks @ Josh jolly , i am curious to know what /dev/null is since am new to unix .

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device - it is a special file which discards everything written to it.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh` you can do

```
ls > a > b > c
```

to redirect into multiple files at the same times. Unfortunately this won't work with `bash`.

Comment: i am using ksh @ismail

Comment: @pravin_23 keep it as a future reference :)